# What could リル mean in this situation?

Tags: translation, words

I'm reading a children's story called きつつき商売. Here's an excerpt:

> 『音屋』
>
> それだけでは、なんだか分かりにくいので、きつつきは、そのあとにこう、書きました。
>
> 「できたての音、すてきないい音、おきかせします。四分音符一こにつき、どれでも１００リル」

I'm assuming リル is some sort of currency, but all of my normal internet searches aren't helping me figure out specifically what it is. What could リル mean in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be the currency the woodpecker is selling its sounds for.

It seems other people where wondering the same thing, including native speakers so this is definitely a word made up for the story, and it isn't made very clear in the story either.

See [this Q&A](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/1212795.html) where someone asked the same question (and how to read `野ねずみ`).

> 「リル」と言うお金の単位を[聞]いたことはありませんので、きっとこのお話の中でのみ使われる、作者が作った単位でしょうね。

[This blogpost](http://plaza.rakuten.co.jp/chi9677/diary/200909270000/) also talks about this story, and if you do a quick search for リル on the page you'll find several people in the comments wondering what this currency may actually be, how much it's worth...

Comment: ♩ is [四分音符]{しぶおんぷ}, not 四分音*譜*. (そのブログを書いた人は、漢字を間違ってます)

Comment: @Chocolate I guess you're right, I first thought that musically a **single** quarter note doesn't make much sense, but it's the rate _per_ quarter note and anyway grammatically would be weird so...
I removed this unnecessary remark from the answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It's just a currency made up for the story. I don't think it has any special meaning.